# OpenWrt (Chaos Calmer 15.05.1): `opkg install <package> -d ram` is failing

Tags: package-management, openwrt

When I try to install python-xml using
`opkg install python-xml -d ram`

It goes through the following steps:

- Installing... [WORKS]
- Downloading... [WORKS]
- Configuring... [FAILS]

The configuring step fails with errors...

`grep: /usr/lib/opkg/info/<package>.control No such file or directory 
cat: can't open '/usr/lib/opkg/info/<package>.list' No such file or directory`

The files `opkg` is looking for are in the directory: `/tmp/usr/lib/opkg/info`

**PROBLEM:** `opkg` should be looking to the `/tmp` directory when using the `–d dest_name` parameter

Does anyone know how to get the configuring step to use `/tmp` as the root?

*NOTE: I found an [open ticket](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/20646) on openwrt.org, but it doesn't specify a workaround.*

Comment: You should link to the "open ticket"